# Get result from Json file with Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this Json file:

```
   [{ "id": "2719986", "orario": "00:30", "casa": "Bahia", "trasferta": "Internacional" } , { "id": "2719991", "orario": "02:00", "casa": "Palmeiras", "trasferta": "Botafogo RJ" }]
```

I'm tryng to extract with ajax method, but response is undefined.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "load.php",
      success: function(data) {           
          var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);              
          var id = data.id;
          var orario = data.orario;
          var casa = data.casa;
          var trasferta = data.trasferta;
          var matches = orario+" "+casa+" "+trasferta+"";                         
          console.log(matches); 
        }
    });
```

thanks for all!

Comment: What do you get when you do console.log(data) inside `success`?

Comment: you are missing a `[` at the start of your json string.

Comment: sorry bad copied. added now [

with console.log(data) get all json file correctly.

Comment: So what troubleshooting have you done? Not much information to work from here

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` or `for-loop` to extract data `object`, Your data is coming in `array` from.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "load.php",
        success: function(response) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            response.forEach(function(data) {
                var id = data.id;
                var orario = data.orario;
                var casa = data.casa;
                var trasferta = data.trasferta;
                var matches = orario + " " + casa + " " + trasferta + "";
                console.log(matches);
        })
    }
});
```

```js
var response = [{
    "id": "2719986",
    "orario": "00:30",
    "casa": "Bahia",
    "trasferta": "Internacional"
}, {
    "id": "2719991",
    "orario": "02:00",
    "casa": "Palmeiras",
    "trasferta": "Botafogo RJ"
}];

response.forEach(function(data) {
    var id = data.id;
    var orario = data.orario;
    var casa = data.casa;
    var trasferta = data.trasferta;
    var matches = orario + " " + casa + " " + trasferta + "";
    console.log(matches);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data object you have defined contains two arrays.

In your ajax success callback you need to iterate over the array items like this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data); //No need to use jQuery parse here
data.forEach(function(dataItem){
    var id = dataItem.id;
    var orario = dataItem.orario;
    var casa = dataItem.casa;
    var trasferta = dataItem.trasferta;
    var matches = orario+" "+casa+" "+trasferta+"";                         
    console.log(matches); 
})
```

Comment: Best solution! worked for me. thank you very much :)